# javascript modify subindex of string array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to change subindex of string array but it's not modifing.There is the jsbin [link](http://jsbin.com/bebakisufe/edit?js,console).

```js
function LetterCapitalize(str) {
  var arr = str.split(" ");

  var nstr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    var ltr = arr[i][0];
    console.log('ltr: ' + ltr.toUpperCase());
    arr[i][0] = ltr.toUpperCase();
    nstr += arr[i] + " ";
  }
  str = nstr.trim();
  console.log("result: " + str);
  return str;
}

LetterCapitalize("hello world");
```

Comment: because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```js
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
    var arr = str.split(" ");

    var nstr = "";
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase()+arr[i].slice(1);
        nstr+=   arr[i] + " ";
    }

    str = nstr.trim();    

  console.log("result: " + str);

  return str; 

}

console.log(LetterCapitalize("hello world"));
```

The line that does the difference is the following:

```
arr[i] = arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
```

What we are doing here is to capitalize the first letter of the string at `arr[i]` and then concatenate the capitalized letter with the rest letters.

Comment: Instead of concatenate in nstr variable better to use `return arr.join(' ');`

Answer (score 2):

That's because (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access):

> For character access using bracket notation, attempting to delete or assign a value to these properties will not succeed. The properties involved are neither writable nor configurable.

I.e. strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

You could as well just use `string.replace` matching the first char in each word, using a callback function to upper case the character.

Something like this.

```js
var str = "hello world";

var newStr = str.replace(/\b(\w)/g, function(chr) {
  return chr.toUpperCase()
})

console.log(newStr)
```